# How can I export and then import taxonomy terms?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

So I built my own custom entity type (we'll call it notes). And on my notes I have fields that use taxonomy terms, however when it comes to exporting the data out on individual fields, it shows the data, but when I restart the site and re-import everything, the taxonomy terms don't get imported with it.

Taxonomy terms is pretty important and a core with Drupal, so I don't understand why we can't export and import them easily like with the other data.

So I end up with fields that do not have taxonomy terms or is reported as missing.

Is there a way I can do this so when I import, the taxonomy terms get imported too?

Answer (score 2):

The line between config/content can be blurry since there are many use scenarios. Drupal assumes a default scenario where terms are user-edited content that's not part of the CMS configuration.

Taxonomy terms are content entities, unlike taxonomy vocabularies, which are config entities. Hence, the D8 configuration export/import will not work for taxonomy terms.

There are various modules that will let you import content (and thus taxonomy terms). Some are more general-purpose (e.g. the migration framework, the [content sync](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_sync) module), others are specific to taxonomy (e.g. [taxonomy import](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_import) module). Research solutions and figure out what works best for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [YAML Content](https://www.drupal.org/project/yaml_content). Even if it is not covered by the Drupal Security, it may cover your current needs as it will help you exporting and importing your terms.